# How can I save this matplotlib figure such that the x-axis labels are not cropped out?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am running the following snippet of code in the ipython notebook, using the `pandas` data analysis library along with `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
titles = {'gradStat_p3': "P3:  Gradiometers", 'magStat_p3': "P3:  Magnetometers",
          'gradStat_mmn': "MMN:  Gradiometers", 'magStat_mmn': "MMN:  Magnetometers"}

scales = {'gradStat': (-2.0 * 1e-22, 3.5 * 1e-22), 'magStat': (-1.6 * 1e-25, 4.5 * 1e-25)}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 5))
fig.tight_layout()
for c, component in enumerate(('p3', 'mmn')):
    for s, sensor in enumerate(('gradStat', 'magStat')):
        key = sensor + '_' + component
        axes[c, s].set_ylim(scales[sensor])
        agg = aggregated[key]
        # Plot
        agg.plot(ax=axes[c, s], kind='bar', legend=False, title=titles[key])
        axes[c, s].set_xticklabels(agg.index.format(names=False))
        if not c:  # hide the labels
            axes[c, s].xaxis.set_visible(False)

        saveFile = '/tmp/ERF_comparative_barplot.pdf'
        fig.savefig(saveFile)
```

When the above code is executed, the following (correct) plot is produced in the ipython notebook's inline graphical output:

[image: Correct format]

Note that the x-lables are correctly displayed.

When the image is saved, however, the x-labels are cropped as such:

[image: Erroneous format]

I have tried calling `fig.savefig(savefile, bbox_inches=0`, but to no avail.  How can I avoid this cropping?

**NOTE:** For your convenience, I have pickled the `aggregated` variable [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/aggregated.pickle).  This is a dictionary of pandas DataFrame objects and it *should* be all you need to run the above code and reproduce the bug (assuming you have pandas v.0.8.1 installed).

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `fig.tight_layout()`.

```
fig, ax = subplots(1,1,1)
ax.plot(np.random.randn(5))
ax.set_xticklabels(['this is a very long label', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], rotation=90)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Comment: Hello again!  And thanks again!  It works perfectly.  I *really* owe you a beer, now...